# Is it natural to say "she had her fake eye attached"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

An old person had a bad eye and the surgeon took it out and put a fake eye in.

Do we have a common term to express that action?

For example, "**she had her fake eye attached / installed / joined ...**"

Comment: Normally you wouldn't say "fake eye".  Formally it's an "ocular prosthesis" and colloquially it's usually a "glass eye" or an "artificial eye".  The word "fake" implies malicious intent to fool others.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Though we might use similar language for some other prosthetics without such implication, like "false teeth."

Comment: An ocular prosthesis that is an entire eye is not joined, attached or installed. And generally speaking, this is not done for old people, it is done for people who are missing an eye or have an eye injury. I really do not want to google this because I only do medical through Duckduckgo and it's just too much work.,

Comment: Where's your research?

Comment: @Lambie is correct about a full eye replacement not being an "old person" operation. The most common age-related eye surgery is a cataract surgery where only the cornea (lens) of the eye is replaced. In that case, we would say, "she had her artificial cornea **implanted**".

Comment: @AndyBonner - I think there's a definite difference between "false" and "fake".  Dentures might be called "false teeth", but if you say "fake teeth", I think more of a Halloween costume with vampire fangs or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that whatever we use here can't necessarily extend to all operations in which a medical professional gives someone an artificial device. For instance, when I enter "I had a pacemaker" into Google, it suggests as autocompletions both "implanted" and "installed."

But an artificial eye is a type of prosthesis, and we often use "fitted" for prosthetics since some customization goes into uniting the device with the person: "She was fitted with an artificial eye." Note the altered syntax; we wouldn't really say "she had an artificial eye fitted." Another, simpler option is to change the syntax again: "She got an artificial eye." This could be used as well for earlier medical times when there might have been less "fitting" involved, like a pirate's peg leg.

Many such prosthetics are only semi-permanently attached, so it's not actually a surgeon that does the final step of providing them. For devices that *are* provided through surgery (like a pacemaker), it's common to add "surgically" to the verb, especially when the procedure is out of the routine and needs more explanation: "The cyborg had an infrared sensor surgically implanted in his eye socket" or "She was such a fan of *Total Recall* she had a third breast surgically attached."